# Arduino Nano - Strange problems

Tags: arduino-nano, sketch

## Update:

**The arduino works only when I connect 3.3v to reset pin. And I successfully uploaded a sketch but it stops when I disconnect 3.3v and reset.**

## Update 2:

**-- Removed --**

## Update 3:

**Its working perfectly and running smoothly for like 5+ min but the problem starts again**

---

I bought a new arduino nano V3 clone. Till now, I have been facing very strange problems with it:

- The pre-uploaded blinking sketch works for a few seconds (like 5 sec and only works when powered after a break) and then it starts to glitch
- The L led stays on or off after that
- Reset button does nothing (No led blinks or anything)
- Can't upload any sketch
- Programmer is not responding
- RX led blinks during uploading (3 times only)
- USB not recognized when connected

Here is what I tried to solve:

- Loopback test > Successful
- Changed ports
- Changed proccessor
- Tried uploading with parallel programming
- Sketch worked with another arduino nano clone
- Manual reset
- Tried with Old bootloader
- Tried uploading sketch with older version of Arduino IDE.

Here is the exact image of one I have:

[image]

Here is the error message:

```
Arduino: 1.8.10 Hourly Build 2019/07/23 10:33 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)"

C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware -tools C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\tools-builder -tools C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\libraries -libraries C:\Users\MN\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328old -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10810 -build-path C:\Users\MN\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_778230 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\MN\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_273206 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5.path=C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\examples\01.Basics\Blink\Blink.ino
C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware -tools C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\tools-builder -tools C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\libraries -libraries C:\Users\MN\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328old -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10810 -build-path C:\Users\MN\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_778230 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\MN\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_273206 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5.path=C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\examples\01.Basics\Blink\Blink.ino
Using board 'nano' from platform in folder: C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\arduino\avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\arduino\avr
Detecting libraries used...
"C:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10810 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\eightanaloginputs" "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o nul
Generating function prototypes...
"C:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10810 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\eightanaloginputs" "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"C:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\tools-builder\\ctags\\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
Compiling sketch...
"C:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10810 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\eightanaloginputs" "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp.o"
Compiling libraries...
Compiling core...
Using precompiled core: C:\Users\MN\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_273206\core\core_arduino_avr_nano_cpu_atmega328old_96bc3f74325b2724b539066aa6a6e44d.a
Linking everything together...
"C:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230/..\\arduino_cache_273206\\core\\core_arduino_avr_nano_cpu_atmega328old_96bc3f74325b2724b539066aa6a6e44d.a" "-LC:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230" -lm
"C:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230/Blink.ino.eep"
"C:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230/Blink.ino.hex"
"C:\\Users\\MN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\arduino-nightly-windows\\arduino-nightly\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-size" -A "C:\\Users\\MN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_778230/Blink.ino.elf"
Sketch uses 924 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM6 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\MN\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_778230/Blink.ino.hex:i 
An error occurred while uploading the sketch

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\MN\Downloads\Compressed\arduino-nightly-windows\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM6
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x85
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x85
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x85
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x85
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x85
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x85
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x85
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x85
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x85
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x85

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

What is wrong with my arduino?

<sub>Note: I was uploading the blink (Example) code, tried with others too...</sub>

Comment: What kind of power supply do you use? Does it work with other sources (e.g. USB ports)? Can you hook up an oscilloscope to the crystal pins?

Comment: @Erlkoenig Same happens when powered with the 5V arduino power supply.

Comment: @Erlkoenig Which pins are the crystal pins?

Comment: Just to eliminate a possibility, Do you have another computer you can try it with?

Comment: @GMc I don't have any other computer, but as I have already mentioned I tried the same sketch with another nano and it worked

Comment: Sorry I missed that. FWIW, The crystal is (most likely) the little silver box next to the CPU chip. It will (most likely) have something like 16.0MHz engraved on it. Here is a link that includes a photo showing where the crystal is (scroll down a bit) http://www.circuitstoday.com/arduino-nano-tutorial-pinout-schematics

Comment: You can look up the MCU's data sheet and look for the "XTAL" pins, which are probably easier to contact than the crystal pins themselves. While you're at it, also check the voltage supply and reset input with the oscilloscope...

Comment: I don't have any oscilloscope

Comment: did you solder the headers?

Comment: @Juraj Yeah, I soldered them.

Comment: check the soldering for shorts

Comment: Nope, Its perfectly soldered

Comment: @Juraj Check the update

Comment: you have some week solder connection between reset and ground pin. it pulls the reset down holding the MCU in reset.

Comment: So should I resolder?

Comment: take a magnifying glass and check it. maybe it only needs a little cleaning. check both reset pins

Comment: and check the ICSP header too

Comment: @Juraj I resoldered and cleaned it. It worked constantly for like a min but its now in the same state again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96755/discussion-between-black-thunder-and-juraj).

Comment: Check the soldering on the SMD resistors. It could be that the pullup on RESET is not connected properly.

Comment: @Majenko Not sure but all smd resistors seem to be good

Comment: Here is a video https://youtu.be/MMiZEQKPJMM

Comment: why only use external power without going through USBport as data input

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri I tried with usb port too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When soldering the pin headers, I used too much flux. So this caused contact between the GND and RST on the ICSP causing the arduino to stay in the reset position. I removed the ICSP pin headers and there was a lot of flux. I removed it and now my arduino is working perfectly. Thanks to @Juraj for figuring it out that there must be a contact between GND and RST

Answer (score 1):

The compiler log said:

`-libraries C:\Users\MN\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328old -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10810`

It seems your AVR is not updated, try to update your `Arduino Avr Bords` on the boards manager. also make sure your `avrdude.conf` file might to be :

`...
Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
...`

Dont forget to wire RX to GND or connected RX to TX directly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But wasn't the arduino supposed to work with the old loaded sketch with external power provided?

Comment: Yes it should be work using 3v or 5v, same to me, based your error message, you can try my way cause the nano have auto-reset of the arduino-nightly.

Comment: Did you try to change in the `Tools` menu from `Atmega328P(OldBootloader)` to `Atmega328P` #NewBootloader. See at `Detecting...` section and `Compiling...` are difference using of fqdn.

Comment: I have almost tried everything. I will try your way later

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is missing the 10K reset pullup resistor.  Try adding one from the RST pin to VCC, which is pin 2 of the 6-pin header.

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually explain too much.  Can you provide detail about it?

Comment: Reset pin without a pullup resistor can float, leading to odd results as the Nano can reset intermittently. The resistor keeps that from happening.  I don't see on in the picture presented.

Comment: What if it has on the underneath? Can you please show me through pictures cause its hard for me to understand.

Comment: Sure - post pictures of the top and bottom of Your card - I don't have one of those myself.